# Como criar uma array com object a partir de uma consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, array

Preciso do seguinte resultado dentro de uma variável a partir de uma consulta **PHP** + **MySQL**:

```
array(1) {
    [0] => object(stdClass) #1 (3) { 
    ["id"]= > string(2) "1" 
    ["nome"] => string(5) "teste" 
    ["email"] => string(18) "contato@teste.com.br"
    }
}
```

O resultado acima se obtém assim:

```
$results = array((object) array( 
      'id' => '1', 
      'nome' => 'teste', 
      'email' => 'contato@teste.com.br'
    ));
```

> > UPDATE: Caso eu tenha de 1 ou mais ID's, ou seja, 1 ou mais nomes e emails

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2195 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "1"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(16) "testao"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "teste@gmail.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2196 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "2"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(17) "testado"
    ["sml_email"]=>
    string(18) "dasdas@dsfdfgs.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código da sua consulta e até aonde vc foi na tentativa de fazer o array.

Comment: Não sei como cria essa consulta com object, essa é a pergunta. Pode ajudar com qualquer consulta exemplo? O array criei manualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conectar ao banco de dados MySQL:

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Fazendo o Select no banco de dados:

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

No seu caso você pode pegar os valores retornados e jogar direto:

```js
$results = array((object) array( 
      'id' => $row["id"], 
      'nome' => $row["nome"], 
      'email' => $row["email"]
    ));
```

Sem ter os seus dados para usar de exemplo fica difícil. Mas acredito que com esse código você consiga conectar ao banco de dados, fazer o select e montar o array.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Para fazer no loop com o select do banco é assim:

```js
$newArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
 
 $newArray[] = array(


 'id' => $row["id"], 
        'nome' => $row["nome"], 
        'email' => $row["email"]


           );

    }
}
```

No código acima vc coloca um array dentro de outra, talvez isso esteja te confundindo.

Olha esse [fiddler](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/au2f-x290) e ve se fica mais fácil, nele eu colo um objeto dentro do array. Acredito que será melhor no seu caso, mas de novo, sem os seu código para pegar e alterar é difícil entender o que vc realmente precisa.

Comment: Tem um porem...Caso eu tenha de 1 a 100 `ID's`, ou seja, 1 a 100 `nomes` e `emails`?? PERGUNTA EDITATA!

Comment: Basta fazer no loop, editei a resposta.

Comment: E o `object`???

Comment: Dentro do array você coloca o que quiser, pode até colocar um new MinhaClasse() {dado = valor, dado1 = valor1}... Aí você faz qualquer coisa.

Comment: Ele está me trazendo `[0] => array(1) {` antes do `object(stdClass)`, como resolver?

Comment: Editei a resposta, isso é pq vc coloca um array dentro do outro, olha o fiddler que eu fiz usando um objeto montado, bem mais facil de entender, aí vc carrega cada novo objeto com os dados do banco e joga ele no array. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/au2f-x290

Answer (score 1):

Basta que atribuas este retorno a uma nova variável, fazendo o seguinte:

## Retorno como objecto:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

if($query = $con->query('SELECT * FROM exemplo LIMIT 5')){
    while($resultado = $query->fetch_object()){
        $obj[] = $resultado;
    }
}

print_r($obj);

?>
```

## Retorno como associação convertido à saída

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

if($query = $con->query('SELECT * FROM exemplo LIMIT 5')){
    while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $obj[] = (object) $resultado;
    }
}

print_r($obj);

?>
```

Para retornar os resultados basta que os percorras como qualquer outro objecto, mas dentro de um loop:

```
foreach($obj as $key=>$val){
    # imprime o indice da array 
    # e o respectivos valores de cada objecto nessa array
    print "#{$key} " . $obj[$key]->titulo . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir como falou, utilize a função abaixo:

```
public function listar(){   //new Pessoa(id, nome, telefone, endereco)
$query = "SELECT *FROM pessoa ";            
try {               
    $stmt = $this->conexao->mysqli->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            array[] = $row;
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $this->array;
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao buscar dados";
    }
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

}

Para chamar a função, faça:

```
$exemplo = new daoPessoa();
$pessoa = $exemplo->listar();

<!-- para imprimir organizado faça: -->
<pre>
<?php print_r(pessoa); ?>
<pre>
```